# Why is the hex representation 89 not printing correctly as ‰ after using toString in Java?

Tags: java, string, hex, tostring, xor

After performing XORs and converting from Hex to string, I was expecting the hex value "89" to display as "‰", but instead Eclipse shows "?".  While debugging, the character is actually blank.  Why?

1. I have the string "r" which I convert to hex => "72".
2. I then XOR the "72" with "FB" (û) => "89".
3. I then convert "89" to string using this function:

   ```
   public static String HexToString(String hex){
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

     for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){

         //grab the hex in pairs
         String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));

         //convert hex to decimal
         int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);

         //convert the decimal to character
         sb.append((char)decimal);

         temp.append(decimal);
     }
     System.out.println("Decimal : " + temp.toString());

     return sb.toString();
     }
   ```

After printing the result to the console, I'm seeing "?" instead of "‰".  What is wrong?

Edit:
Here is a screenshot showing the value of decimal and the debug value of (char)decimal.
[image: (char)decimal]

Comment: @D3mon That won't help; the weirdness happens during `System.out.println` itself, and I'd lay money on it being because the system encoding is CP1252 (or one of its close siblings), i.e., that it's on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, Java is fully Unicode internally (though not the latest version of Unicode, for complex reasons that don't matter here). 89 hex would be `\u0089` which is an extended control character (Character Tabulation With Justification), just as it is in the character set [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1); Unicode is precisely the same as ISO-8859-1 for the first 256 characters. From your description, I guess you're on Windows and have things configured to use the [CP1252 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which interprets 89 hex as `‰` but conversion from Unicode is done (during printing to the console) by mapping to equivalent characters, not just blatting the bytes out; because that C1 control character has no equivalent in CP1252, it ends up as the replacement character (a question mark in this case).

The moral of this story is that *characters are **not** bytes* and you need to be very careful with charsets when working in this area. (Or you should use a fully Unicode system, where these problems largely go away, though at a cost of characters being much more complex entities than before.)

Comment: But, how can we improve the above code to get the desired result ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani It's a massively wrong-headed thing to do… but use `System.out.write(decimal);` which writes a specified byte out without interpretation. Just remember, you're getting yourself into a gigantic mess here. What you are doing is not portable. What you are doing is not elegant. What you are doing is bad practice.

Comment: It's for one of the optional Programming assignments in an online Cryptography course I'm taking.  The question's ciphers are all in hex and we have to get the key (since it was used on multiple messages) in order to decipher a message.  How else should we convert from Hex to String and back again?  And how should we perform the XORs?  Right now I'm doing it to the hex values (and it seems to be working correctly).  Also, is there a way to expand the charset in Eclipse so that the print function displays the correct character?